# Subsequences whose sum of digits is divisible by 6

Tags: string, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, subsequence

Say I have a string whose characters are nothing but digits in [0 - 9] range. E.g: "2486". Now I want to find out all the subsequences whose sum of digits is divisible by 6. E.g: in "2486", the subsequences are - "6", "246" ( 2+ 4 + 6 = 12 is divisible by 6 ), "486" (4 + 8 + 6 = 18 is divisible by 6 ) etc. I know generating all 2^n combinations we can do this. But that's very costly. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Edit:

I found the following solution somewhere in quora.

```
int len,ar[MAXLEN],dp[MAXLEN][MAXN];

int fun(int idx,int m)

{

    if(idx==len)

        return (m==0);

    if(dp[idx][m]!=-1)

        return dp[idx][m];

    int ans=fun(idx+1,m);

    ans+=fun(idx+1,(m*10+ar[idx])%n);

    return dp[idx][m]=ans;

}

int main()

{

    // input len , n , array

    memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));

    printf("%d\n",fun(0,0));            

    return 0;

}
```

Can someone please explain what is the logic behind the code - 'm*10+ar[idx])%n' ? Why is m multiplied by 10 here?

Comment: How can you *not* generate all  2^n combinations ? can you disqualify a subsequence before checking it ?

Comment: Just thinking about the operations needed to be done: first, addition. Since we cannot determine whether a six multiple is reached before completing the operation, there is no way to reduce operations there. And then checking divisibility is only one operation. Intuitively, there is no way to further simplify and still get exact results.

Comment: The problem can be reduced. I am trying to reduce it to subset sum problem. Generating all combinations is not an effective method at all for large strings.

Comment: You want the number of subsequences or rather you want to print them all?

Comment: I want both @ShubhamSharma

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a sequence of 16 digits You could generate all 2<sup>16</sup> subsequences and test them, which is 65536 operations.

Or you could take the first 8 digits and generate the 2<sup>8</sup> possible subsequences, and sort them based on the result of their sum modulo 6, and do the same for the last 8 digits. This is only 512 operations.

Then you can generate all subsequences of the original 16 digit string that are divisible by 6 by taking each subsequence of the first list with a modulo value equal to 0 (including the empty subsquence) and concatenating it with each subsequence of the last list with a modulo value equal to 0.

Then take each subsequence of the first list with a modulo value equal to 1 and concatenate it with each subsequence of the last list with a modulo value equal to 5. Then 2 with 4, 3 with 3, 4 with 2 and 5 with 1.

So after an initial cost of 512 operations you can generate just those subsequences whose sum is divisible by 6. You can apply this algorithm recursively for larger sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with a 6-bit bitmap for each position in the string. Work from right to left and set the array of bitmaps so that bitmaps have bits set in the array when there is some subsequence starting from just after the array which sums up to that position in the bitmap. You can do this from right to left using the bitmap just after the current position. If you see a 3 and the bitmap just after the current position is 010001 then sums 1 and 5 are already accessible by just skipping the 3. Using the 3 sums 4 and 2 are now available, so the new bitmap is 011011.

Now do a depth first search for subsequences from left to right, with the choice at each character being either to take that character or not. As you do this keep track of the mod 6 sum of the characters taken so far. Use the bitmaps to work out whether there is a subsequence to the right of that position that, added to the sum so far, yields zero. Carry on as long as you can see that the current sum leads to a subsequence of sum zero, otherwise stop and recurse.

The first stage has cost linear in the size of the input (for fixed values of 6). The second stage has cost linear in the number of subsequences produced. In fact, if you have to actually write out the subsequences visited (E.g. by maintaining an explicit stack and writing out the contents of the stack) THAT will be the most expensive part of the program.

The worst case is of course input 000000...0000 when all 2^n subsequences are valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure a user named, amit, recently answered a similar question for combinations rather than subsequences where the divisor is 4, although I can't find it right now. His answer was to create, in this case, five arrays (call them `Array_i`) in `O(n)` where each array contains the array elements with a modular relationship `i` with 6. With subsequences we also need a way to record element order. For example, in your case of `2486`, our arrays could be:

```
Array_0 = [null,null,null,6]
Array_1 = []
Array_2 = [null,4,null,null]
Array_3 = []
Array_4 = [2,null,8,null]
Array_5 = []
```

Now just cross-combine the appropriate arrays, maintaining element order: Array_0, Array_2 & Array_4, Array_0 & any other combination of arrays:

```
6, 24, 48, 246, 486
```